# How can I nest a Rails erb <%= with in a <%= %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a partial that I am using on several pages that require an array to be passed from the views.

```
<div id="help-modal" class="hidden">
  <%=  render 'unit_setup_help', troubleshoot: "Unit Troubleshooting", message: <%= yield(:message_array) %>  %>
</div>
```

I want `message: message_array`, with `message_array` be passed via the view.

I tried doing `message: "#{yield(:message_array)}"` but then I get an array with nested inside quotes. For example:

```
<% msg_array = ["Don't choose wrong one or you will die" ,"choose wrong one or you will die"] %>

<% content_for :message_array do  %>
  <%= msg_array %>
<% end %>
```

I get this error:

> undefined method `each' for #

And this what my result looks like:

```
=> "    [&quot;Don't choose wrong one or you will die", "choose wrong one or you will die"]\n"
```

Comment: You can't nest, but it's not clear to me why you'd ever need to. Set your `message` value before you call the template string that needs it--pass it to the partial.

Comment: Bro, I just found a way better way to do this. I can just use controller variables!

Comment: That's what I said, but glad you worked it out. For partials I'd still pass it in instead of relying on instance variables because it's more versatile.

Comment: I am still using partials, I am just no longer defining my values in the view... just the controller... as I should have been already!